# Can not run a sudo script without password?

Tags: scripting, sudo, i3

I'm using arch linux - i3. I have a script to run `rmmod hid-multitouch && sudo modprobe hid-multitouch`. I edited the hot key in i3 and set an exception to run a script without password using `sudo visudo` to uncomment and added the lines

`%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh`
`hieuc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh`
But it seem like it is not working right know, but a few days ago it still worked for me.
Here is an output of `/etc/sudoers`

```
## sudoers file.
##
## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
## Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
## that prevent sudo from running.
##
## See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
##

##
## Host alias specification
##
## Groups of machines. These may include host names (optionally with wildcards),
## IP addresses, network numbers or netgroups.
# Host_Alias    WEBSERVERS = www1, www2, www3

##
## User alias specification
##
## Groups of users.  These may consist of user names, uids, Unix groups,
## or netgroups.
# User_Alias    ADMINS = millert, dowdy, mikef

##
## Cmnd alias specification
##
## Groups of commands.  Often used to group related commands together.
# Cmnd_Alias    PROCESSES = /usr/bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/renice, \
#               /usr/bin/pkill, /usr/bin/top
# Cmnd_Alias    REBOOT = /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff

##
## Defaults specification
##
## You may wish to keep some of the following environment variables
## when running commands via sudo.
##
## Locale settings
# Defaults env_keep += "LANG LANGUAGE LINGUAS LC_* _XKB_CHARSET"
##
## Run X applications through sudo; HOME is used to find the
## .Xauthority file.  Note that other programs use HOME to find   
## configuration files and this may lead to privilege escalation!
# Defaults env_keep += "HOME"
##
## X11 resource path settings
# Defaults env_keep += "XAPPLRESDIR XFILESEARCHPATH XUSERFILESEARCHPATH"
##
## Desktop path settings
# Defaults env_keep += "QTDIR KDEDIR"
##
## Allow sudo-run commands to inherit the callers' ConsoleKit session
# Defaults env_keep += "XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
##
## Uncomment to enable special input methods.  Care should be taken as
## this may allow users to subvert the command being run via sudo.
# Defaults env_keep += "XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER"
##
## Uncomment to use a hard-coded PATH instead of the user's to find commands
# Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
##
## Uncomment to send mail if the user does not enter the correct password.
# Defaults mail_badpass
##
## Uncomment to enable logging of a command's output, except for
## sudoreplay and reboot.  Use sudoreplay to play back logged sessions.
# Defaults log_output
# Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
# Defaults!/usr/local/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
# Defaults!REBOOT !log_output

##
## Runas alias specification
##

##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh
## User
hieuc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh

## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow any user to run sudo if they know the password
## of the user they are running the command as (root by default).
# Defaults targetpw  # Ask for the password of the target user
# ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL  # WARNING: only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

My script:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo rmmod hid-multitouch && sudo modprobe hid-multitouch
```

Here is my hot key in i3 `bindsym $mod+Shift+o exec $HOME/i3script/rmod_hid.sh`

Comment: #Vlastimil
Yes, I edited through visudo
#Thomas
I used xclip so it look different, here is my /etc/visudoers
https://github.com/mrhieu059/archlinux/blob/master/1.txt

Comment: I have copied the linked file to your question

Comment: You don't have to give wheel specific and general access. (but this is not causing your problem)

Comment: Are you running the script with `sudo /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh` or `cd /home/hieuc/i3script/; sudo ./rmod_hid.sh`?

Comment: I commented wheel, and give only for my user specific access, it still not worked :(

Comment: Note: naming scripts ending `.sh` is bad practice`. It violated encapsulation principle, and will lead to maintenance problems. For example when you change the implementation language. (but this is not causing your problem)

Comment: Normally. I cd `cd /home/hieuc/i3script/ then run ./rmod_hid.sh (without sudo prefix) And it didn't ask me passwork and work well`
But I don't know why it doesn't work with i3 hotkey

Comment: This is my first script, I don't know anything about script I just follow other script and do the same thing. Thanks for you advice

Comment: I think I see your problem (see my answer). You are thinking that `sudoers` gives a script permission to run `sudo`. This is not how it works. It gives a user permission to run a script with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `/home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh` is your script, you should be able run `sudo /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh` without needing a password. The sudo rights apply the the command specified, not to commands called from a script named in the sudo config.

Your script on the other hand won't require sudo, as it already runs as root.

```
#! /bin/bash
rmmod hid-multitouch && modprobe hid-multitouch
```

If you want to be able to call your script without sudo, you can check the user id:

```
#! /bin/bash
test "$(id -u)" != 0 && exec sudo /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh "$@"
rmmod hid-multitouch && modprobe hid-multitouch
```

This will call itself with `sudo` if it was called without `sudo`. The script invoked with `sudo` will then execute the commands in the last line as root.

Comment: You can use `$0` to call your self.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I could, but the script may be in the user's PATH and called without a path, but not be in to PATH used by sudo, and therefor not found.

Comment: As it is, it is not portable. You could use `$(which $0)`, though this is not portable across OS.

Comment: It work when I run directly by cd /home/hieuc/i3script then ./rmod_hid.sh. But when I use hotkey code to run it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

The script that you mention in `sudoers`, is the script that you will run with `sudo`.

So if you want to do `sudo /home/me/my-script`, then `/home/me/my-script` must be mentioned in `sudoers`

In your case you can add `modprobe hid-multitouch` to `sudoers`

---

You can also write script1 to contain
`sudo script2`

and put script 2 into `sudoers`.

e.g.

`script1` is called by the hotkey code. It is not mentioned in `suderes`
it contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_called_as="$0"
script_full_name="$(readlink -e "$script_called_as")"
script_dir="$(dirname "$script_full_name")"

sudo "$script_dir/«script2»"
```

Replace `«script2»` with the name of your script.
Then tell `sudeers` about your script2 (not script1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?
I use hotkey to run this script so I added the sudo inside the script with i3wm.
I mentioned it in this line: `hieuc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh`
How to add modprobe hid-multitouch to sudoers? I don't know how to add it?
Sorry for my dumb question

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: I Got you, but I still new with the script.
I don't understand the code above?
`#!/bin/bash
script_dir="$($HOME/i3script/ "$(readlink -e "0")")
sudo "$script_dir/rmod_hid.sh"
`

Comment: Does it right??

Comment: The first line says, use bash as an interpreted. The 2nd line gets the name of the script, as called e.g. `./script1`. The 3rd line gets the full name, it does that by calling readlink, the `$(…)` means run this command, and then replace the `$(…)` with the output of the command. Then the 4th line says get the directory part of the full name. Now we know the name of the directory, we can find the other script, and run it (line 6).

Comment: I got this error, it seem like it cannot find my script dir.
./script1: line4: script_full_name: command not found
./script1: line4: /home/hieuc/i3script: Is a directory
######## This is my script

#!/bin/bash
script_called_as="$rmod_hid"
script_full_name="$(readlink -e "$script_called_as")
script_dir="$(/home/hieuc/i3script "$(script_full_name)")

sudo "$script_dir/rmod_hid"

Comment: No no no. Those are not place holders for you to fill in. The computer will do that. The only code to change in script1 is the word `script2`. Also ensure there is no space before the `=`s.

Comment: I got you, I use full your code and only change the script2 into my script name. But it show sudo: /rmod_hid.sh: command not found :(

Comment: Sorry there where missing quotes. I found the errors (and fixed answer), by adding `set -x` as 2nd line, then running the script. This puts the shell into trace mode. It produces a log of what it is doing. Other techniques are to use a text editor with syntax highlighting (it shows the error as you type). Or to echo the variables after setting them, to check that they are set correctly.

Comment: The script is work but it not work with i3 hotkey :(

Comment: You will now have to ask another question (only one question, per question).

Answer (score 1):

```
hieuc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh
```

This line in sudoers file allows user *hieuc* to execute `/home/hieuc/i3script/rmod_hid.sh` with `sudo` without prompting for a password. For example:

```
hieuc$: sudo ~/i3script/rmod_hid.sh
```

As the script already is running as root, you do not need to use `sudo` inside the script.

Note that having an user-writeable file that can be run using sudo means that the user can run any command as root (by modifying that script).

Comment: While this answer is a duplicate, the last paragraph is **very** important.

Comment: What happen if I use a hotkey to run this command? It won't let me use sudo as a prefix into script so that why I need to add the sudo inside it.

Comment: You could test uid and run `sudo` inside the script, something like: `if [ ! "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then exec sudo "$0"; fi`.

Comment: It work when run directly cd /home/hieuc/i3script then run ./rmod_hid.sh
But it doesn't work with hotkey to run through i3